# Xcode is giving me some Thread 1 error, and iOS Simulator is crashing

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

Whenever I try to run my project (in Xcode 4.6.3), it launces the iPhone Sim., the 'screen' on it goes black, and Xcode displays this same exact thing every time

[image: http://d.pr/i/7KBd]

If anything else such as code of the XIB's I'm using**, I would be more than happy to provide those. Thanks!!

**XIB's I'm using ---- whenever I try to link a button to a view controller (in a .storyboard file) it won't link. I two finger click (right click) and drag, usually, the view controller I want to link will be highlighted in blue, and then I am able to just tap it in the Sim., and it will do a quick animation to the next VC. But it the VC I'm trying to link it doesn't even get highlighted. Once again, I'm running Xcode 4.6.3. Thanks again!!

Comment: What's showing in the console window? That may well have more information on the crash. You can also enable breakpoints on all exceptions which might stop you in a more useful place.

Comment: can you show your applicationDidFinishLaunchingWithOptions method from appdelegate.m file

Comment: See http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1

Comment: @Roma `- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}`

Comment: 1) check xib's name. one time i had name viewcontroller-iphone but wrote viewcontroller 2) does this crash happens on all simulator ios versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The picture in your comment says that it crashes when trying to set a key (admissionsButton) for your ViewController object that doesn't exist. This could happen if you deleted a property in code but the IB link still remained. If you open up IB and go to your view controller, expand the utilities window (the right sidebar) and then go to the far right option that shows connections. If there is something there that says admissionsButton, try deleting it.

In order to give you more help than that, I would need to see a more detailed log of where the crash happens.

Comment: Awesome. That worked. I actually had a lot of links that were wrong once I looked thru the whole project's XIB's... I guess I'll be more careful next time I make an app. Now I'm not getting an error, put i simply don't know how to switch views, b/c I'm used to storyboards. I'm using this. `- (IBAction)admissionsButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    Admissions *admissionsVC = [[Admissions alloc] initWithNibName:@"admissionsVC" bundle:nil];
    
    [self.view addSubview:admissionsVC.view];
}` with `#import "Admissions.h"` at the top under the VC import.

Comment: So if your project uses a storyboard, you shouldn't have to use initWithNibName. You should just create a segue from one VC to the other and then execute it with `performSegueWithIdentifier`

Comment: Here is a little more info on storyboards if you would like it: http://www.raywenderlich.com/5191/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-2

Answer (score 0):

That message could be for anything during the execution of your code. I would use breakpoints from the moment of launch and step through it using the debugger window.

Comment: I don't think its even in the code... I have NO clue what it is.

Comment: well, your last sentence ("I have no clue what it is") invalidates the first sentence ("I don't think its even in the code").  You should step through your code in the Xcode debugger.  Start with putting a breakpoint at the end of your "`applicationDidFinishLaunching`" method and just see if the debugger even reaches that.